# Laravel Bulk Insert

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am trying to find solution to below use case, using Laravel I am inserting bulk products with respective quantity and description. For example product1 with id:pro_1 with its quantity and description, same with other products. If I submit the form how I know for which product the quantity and description is.

```
    @foreach(get_products_by_parent_name("Content") as $product_id => $product_name)
                     <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                              <h4><label class="p_name"><input type="checkbox" value="{{ $product_id }}"> {{ $product_name}} </label></h4>
                              <label>Quantity</label>
                              <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" 
                              name="qn_{{$product_id}}">
                              <label>Description</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control" name="desp_{{$product_id}}" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
@endforeach
```

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving all your field names a product ID, you could make them arrays (for example: desp_{{$product_id}} becomes desp[{{$product_id}}]). Looping through the results, you could create a new model with the data given.

Comment: Each box is different with product_id as key.

Comment: But I assume for every box the product_id is the same? You're looping through your products, where every result has a unique key (product_id). So you can access the box sets after submitting because they'll be grouped together in the array based on the given key, in this case the given product_id.

Comment: Every box has different product_id, how to group thats my main concern.

Comment: Yes, so because every box has a different product_id you know which description/quantity field belongs to which product.